# How to send IM on skype with linux/php?

Tags: php, com, activex, skype

i've search this for a long time and didn't find something useful, Skype provides an [ActiveX object](http://developer.skype.com/accessories) but is it just for windows? if it works for linux, is there any example codes to interact with it? Or better yet, is there any web API, or some IM gateway that supports skype?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your small Web API in C#/C/C++/VB.NET/ASP.NET (pick your favorite Windows language here) and run it under windows. Then, from your Linux/PHP box just invoke your small WEB API.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look at pidgin and libpurple (http://www.pidgin.im/)
Pidgin provides API and exists also a plugin for skype (http://eion.robbmob.com/)

You can write your own wrapper based on pidgin API and later call it via PHP